# Salesforce IDE Question: Windows Mavensmate autocomplete not working

Tags: apex, ide, mavensmate, sublime, atom

I have installed the latest version of mavensmate and sublime editor and Atom editor on my windows machine. but autocomplete works in neither editor.
can't find any useful information from google. but it will be really convenient to  have autocomplete.

for autocomplete, I mean when you create a new object, it gives you hints of all the fields of that object. when you create a new instance of some class, it gives you the methods options.

what should I do to make it work?